# How do I fix this rstrip attribute error?

Tags: python, attributes

I'm using .rstrip to remove \n from the words in the imported text file but its coming up as an attribute error?

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

```
import random
import os
import time

text_file = open ("ten_words.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
missing = random.choice(lines)
random.shuffle(lines)


print ("First Grid")
print ("\n", lines.rstrip[0],"|", lines.rstrip[1], "|", lines.rstrip[2])
print ("\n", lines.rstrip[3],"|", lines.rstrip[4], "|", lines.rstrip[5])
print ("\n", lines.rstrip[6],"|", lines.rstrip[7], "|", lines.rstrip[8])
```

Comment: lines is an array, `rstrip` is a method of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some ordering wrong here, what you want to do is:

```
lines[0].rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

lines is an array, `rstrip` is a method of string

```
import random
import os
import time

text_file = open ("ten_words.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
missing = random.choice(lines)
random.shuffle(lines)


print ("First Grid")
print ("\n", lines[0].rstrip(),"|", lines[1].rstrip(), "|", lines[2].rstrip())
print ("\n", lines[3].rstrip(),"|", lines[4].rstrip(), "|", lines[5].rstrip())
print ("\n", lines[6].rstrip(),"|", lines[7].rstrip(), "|", lines[8].rstrip())
```